# "Excuse I" correctness

Tags: grammar

I had a gentleman say "Excuse I" to me the other day as he passed me in the hallway.  He was a professor at the university I attend, and so it got me thinking:

Is "Excuse I" acceptable grammar even though "Excuse me" is more commonly used?

Comment: Are you sure it was "Excuse I"? When I've heard this joking phrase, it has usually been "Scuse I".

Comment: Is the context British? If it is then the professor could be a West Country man and be using his native dialect in a jokey way. Rather in the way that a Yorkshire man might say "Ey up chuck!" or a Geordie say "Wy Aye" although their normal speech would be Standard English.

Comment: For decades i have said excuse i after a flagrant belch, as a joke, which I thought was an Australian joke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a playful abuse of the language.

"I" is a subject  pronoun, so this would be correct if he were doing the excusing,  and meant the same as "I excuse".  But in an imperative like this, "excuse *me*" is correct.

Answer (score 3):

It is often used although usually tongue in cheek (ie a joke).  I believe it originally comes from people mocking those that replace "me" with "I" thinking that this is correct grammar. In actual fact "me" is the correct pronoun. People often use this without realising the irony in the expression "excuse I".

I believe this "deliberate" error comes from a general incorrect trend to replace "me" with "I" such as "She came to the restaurant with my mum and I".  The "I" should actually be "me" since the preposition makes I me but many now think because there are two people they should say "person X and I".

Comment: Are you saying that many who use the expression now are not aware that they are saying something that originated as being intentionally ungrammatical? That is not my impression—I’ve never heard anyone use it in a way that suggested they were not aware of its ungrammaticality.

Answer (score 3):

The malapropism "Excuse I" is attributable to Dame Edna Everage, a character performed by Barry Humphries.

> Excuse I!'' she said in a high, quavery voice, then sang one of her
>   old songs about her favourite colour, maroon, or ''maroan''

from [The Sydney Morning Herald](http://www.smh.com.au/entertainment/theatre/not-your-average-edna-20120322-1vmp9.html)

Comment: Can you cite an example from Humphries's work of his character's use of the phrase—or even better a third-party source that attributes the origin of the phrase to Humphries?

Comment: I upvoted this answer on the strength of ab2's addition of a link that seems to suggest not only that "Excuse I" is a catchphrase not only of the redoubtable 40-years-along Dame Edna, but also of the early housewife Edna. Thanks, ab2!

Answer (score -2):

It's not correct grammar, but it's a reasonably common colloquial expression.

Comment: Common?  I've never heard it before.

Comment: I agree with Malvolio although I'm not a native speaker but I wonder... How can it be colloquial if he heard it from a _professor_? Usually between professors and students there is some distance, but well, I can't be 100% sure about how it is in U.S....

Comment: @Alenanno: Those pesky professors, always cutting up. Me, I can't recall ever hearing it either.

Comment: I've heard it on several occasions.  But I did qualify "common" with "reasonably".

Comment: If you’ve never heard _excuse I_ before, you obviously haven’t watched enough Graham Norton (which is inexcusable, so pronoun case doesn’t really matter).

Comment: Didn't downvote because this answers the question asked - accurately and exactly but no more than that... and is almost misleading for it! It's a joke - albeit a bit of a hackneyed one now - and the joke _is_ the abuse of grammar and the airs and graces thereby implied. I don't doubt those of us who have heard the phrase all know this, but this is not something that should be left out, I'd think! @JanusBahsJacquet, Graham Norton, alas, deserves no credit here: it is of an older vintage, as pointed out in [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/350077/230552).

Comment: @tmgr I’m sure it predates Dame Edna too—Graham was just the first thing I thought of.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No doubt! (I didn't mean to imply any correction.)